# Multitask Gaussian Process on multiple multivariate time series

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, gaussian-process

I am in the process of working with multitask gaussian processes (the ones introduced by Bonilla et al in this [paper](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/3189-multi-task-gaussian-process-prediction.pdf)).

I am now interested in applying the MGP to multiple multivariate time series.

More concretely, I have multiple patients, each of them is "described" by a multivariate time series (for example the patient's average heartbeat, blood pressure and glucose levels from 0 to 24h)

Usually speaking, MGPs are meant to deal with one such multivariate time series (i.e, one patient). But what is the best way of extending this concept to multiple multivariate time series (i.e, multiple patients)

I've been looking around the web for a bit, but it seems like there's a lack of research and pre existing implementations in this area. I found this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.04152.pdf) which, among other things, implements what I'm asking for. Its way of doing things is sharing all the parameters (kernel parameter, inter task covariance matrix, task noise) across patients, and then training those parameters by "backpropagating" the error all the way back from their classifier instead of training the MGP on its own.

I was wondering if any of you knew more on how to train such MGPs? I was thinking about, for example, training each one individually and then averaging each parameter, but I don't know how sound that is.

Comment: I have the same issue ! It's a really interesting question and indeed " there's a lack of research and pre existing implementations in this area". 
I have look at Hierarchical Gaussian Process that try to use the information of each individual to estimate Population levels... but it seems really complicated to implement.

Do you have found the solution to your problem ?

Comment: Not really, I just ended up sharing the parameters across multivariate time series and optimizing them by putting them in the same tensorflow pipeline as my classifier, which means the error from the classifier was backpropagated all the way to the MGP and used to tune it through automatic differentiation. (similar to what the paper I cited in my original question did)